# How to apply hover event to the element with lower z-index with keeping pointer events of the element with higher z-index

Tags: html, css

I have two div elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">...card container...</div>
  <div class="effect-background">...effect container...</div>
</div>
```

and here are styles of them

```
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.card:hover {
  ...CARD HOVER STYLES...
}
.effect-background{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 9;
}
.effect-background:hover {
  ...BACKGROUND HOVER STYLES...
}
```

but BACKGROUND HOVER STYLES doesn't work when hovering on card div.

I know `pointer-events: none;` CSS but I want to keep CARD HOVER STYLES at the same time.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use: `.card:hover + .effect-background`. You can read more about selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Hope it helped :)

```css
.card {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40vw;
    top: 40vh;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vh;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .card:hover {
      background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
  .effect-background{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  .card:hover + .effect-background {
background-color: pink;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">...card container...</div>
  <div class="effect-background">...effect container...</div>
</div>
```